# Trying to select multiple columns where one is unique

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I am trying to select several columns from a table where one of the columns is unique. The select statement looks something like this:

```
select a, distinct b, c, d  
from mytable
```

The table looks something like this:

```
| a | b | c | d | e |...  
|---|---|---|---|---|   
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5  
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 6  
| 2 | 5 | 7 | 1 | 9  
| 7 | 3 | 8 | 6 | 4  
| 7 | 3 | 8 | 6 | 7
```

So the query should return something like this:

```
| a | b | c | d |  
|---|---|---|---|  
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4  
| 2 | 5 | 7 | 1  
| 7 | 3 | 8 | 6
```

I just want to remove all of the rows where b is duplicated.

**EDIT:** There seems to be some confusion about which row I want to be selected in the case of duplicate b values. I don't care because the a, c, and d *should* (but are not guaranteed to) be the same.

Comment: do you only want the first 4 columns?

Comment: No, I was just using that for the example.

Comment: I think your logic is flawed (or you example not very good) what if they want the 'e' column as well... which value should it pick from the first 2 rows... 5 or 6

Comment: Please provide the exact results you are looking for then.

Comment: Do you care which of the multiple rows you return?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
    SELECT * FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY b ORDER BY a) NO
,* FROM TableName) AS T1 WHERE NO = 1
```

Comment: This works great, thank you. If you don't mind, could you explain why this works? I am having trouble picturing what is going on.

Comment: Pet, Inner query did partition of [b] column and give me the Row number.
Eg 
[No] [b]
1 2
2 2
3 2
1 5
1 7

And Outer query fetch only value 1 from [No] column.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't said how to pick a row for each b value, but this will pick one for each.

```
Select
    a,
    b,
    c,
    d,
    e
From (
    Select
        a,
        b,
        c,
        d,
        e,
        row_number() over (partition by b order by b) rn
    From
        mytable
    ) x
Where
    x.rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are nearly there with `DISTINCT` try:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a, b, c, d
FROM myTable
```

Comment: That selects distinct rows, i.e. all of them. OP appears to want at most one row with each b value.

Comment: @Laurence you may be right, the OP doesn't say which of rows 1 & 2 should be returned.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot put `DISTINCT` on a single column. You should put it right after the `SELECT`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a, b, c, d
FROM mytable
```

It return the result you need for your sample table. However if you require to remove duplicates only from a single column (which is not possible) you probably misunderstood something. Give us more descriptions and sample, and we try to guide you to the right direction.

Comment: That selects distinct rows, i.e. all of them. OP appears to want at most one row with each b value.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care *what* values you get for `B`, `C`, `D`, and `E`, as long as they're appropriate for that key, you can group by `A`:

```
 SELECT A, MIN(B), MIN(C), MIN(D), MIN(E)
 FROM MyTable
 GROUP BY A
```

Note that `MAX()` would be just as valid.  Some RDBMSs support a `FIRST()` aggregate, or similar, for exactly these circumstances where you don't care which value you get (from a certain population).

Comment: The resulting row won't necessarily be a row in the original table.

Comment: Correct.  If the OP does care about that, he needs to specify the rules he wants to use in selecting a row.  If he doesn't care, but he does want all the values from a single row, I think Harshil's solution is best.

Answer (score 0):

This will return what you're looking for but I think your example is flawed because you've no determinism over which value from the `e` column is returned.

```
Create Table A1 (a int, b int, c int, d int, e int)

INSERT INTO A1 (a,b,c,d,e) VALUES (1,2,3,4,5)
INSERT INTO A1 (a,b,c,d,e) VALUES (1,2,3,4,6)
INSERT INTO A1 (a,b,c,d,e) VALUES (2,5,7,1,9)
INSERT INTO A1 (a,b,c,d,e) VALUES (7,3,8,6,4)
INSERT INTO A1 (a,b,c,d,e) VALUES (7,3,8,6,7)

SELECT * FROM A1

SELECT  a,b,c,d
FROM
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY b ORDER BY a) RowNum ,* 
    FROM A1 
) As InnerQuery WHERE RowNum = 1
```