# SQL query help needed - Tale with max date value for each row group

Tags: sql, database

Assume I have a Table like

```
Room    Day People  Theme
A   14/05/2014  12  Water
A   12/05/2014  245 Mathematics
A   05/04/2014  215 Nature
B   10/09/2013  252 Water
B   10/05/2012  221 Cinema
B   05/10/2011  215 Cinema
C   10/10/2013  224 Mathematics
C   02/06/2013  245 Cooking
C   05/03/2013  15  Cooking
```

and want to obtain a Table with a row for each Room A, B and C, together with columns stating the last date it was used, the people attending and the Theme of the conference.

Result will be a Table like that:

```
Room    Day People  Theme
A   14/05/2014  12  Water
B   10/09/2013  252 Water
C   10/10/2013  224 Mathematics
```

This is just an example, the real table contains a lot of rows.

Is there a quick SQL code for obtaining that without stating all the rooms?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: You can use Row_Number() check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18745198/trying-to-select-multiple-columns-where-one-is-unique/18745305#18745305)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this query:

```
SELECT ROOM, MAX(DAY), PEOPLE, THEME 
FROM TABLE_NAME
GROUP BY ROOM, PEOPLE, THEME;
```

Comment: This doesn't result in three records, one per room, but in all nine records in the example, as there are no duplicates for room, People and theme. So this definitely doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

Get the maximum date per room. Then join your table to get the full records:

```
select rooms.*
from rooms
join
(
  select room, max(day) as max_day
  from rooms
  group by room
) last_used on last_used.room = rooms.room and last_used.max_day = room.day;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
With CTE As (
Select room,
        day,
        people,
        theme,
        Row_Number() Over(Partition By Room Order By Day Desc) RowNumber
        )
        Select * From CTE Where RowNumber = 1
```